# Meaning of にまで?

Tags: usage, particle-に, particle-まで

A long time ago, I came across this example sentence in Jisho:

> 彼{かれ}の仕事{しごと}は井戸掘{いどほ}りからゴミの処理{しょり}に**まで**及ぶ{およぶ}。
>   His tasks range from digging wells to getting rid of garbage.

Why does this sentence use *both* に and まで after 処理? Would it be sufficient to have just one or the other, or are both required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

井戸掘りからゴミの処理に及ぶ would sound natural, and already emphasizes how broad his responsibilities are.

Slightly literal translation:

> 井戸掘りからゴミの処理に及ぶ
>   his responsibilities reaches from digging wells to getting rid of garbage

Adding まで strengthens this emphasis

> 井戸掘りからゴミの処理にまで及ぶ
>   his responsibilities reaches from digging wells, to **even** getting rid of garbage

The same まで can be used like this: カリカリに揚げれば、骨まで食べられますよ

`彼の仕事は、井戸掘りからゴミの処理まで及ぶ` sounds a bit odd to me but I'm not sure if it's only me.

Comment: Are you saying that "AからBまで及ぶ" is always ungrammatical, or only in this example? I'm not sure if there is a rule, but there seems to be a few examples [here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89+%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%8A%E3%81%B6) without the `に`.

Comment: @mirka: I think it sounds weird because から〜までwithout に indicates a closed, ordered range (新幹線は九州から青森まで及ぶ、値段は数百円から数千万まで及ぶ). E.g.「訪問した国はインド、ブラジルからイタリアにまで及ぶ」sounds natural but 「インド、ブラジルからイタリアまで及ぶ」sounds a bit odd because it implies the range stops at Italy. But after thinking about it a few times I'm no longer sure!

Comment: Interesting. I agree that "Xまで及ぶ" generally sounds a little odd, and after comparing some Google hits with random nouns it does seem that "Xに及ぶ" is an order of magnitude more common than "Xまで及ぶ". So `に` is at least the default choice (if not the "correct" choice).